# Why am I getting 403 error with CSRF Token - Django - Vue Ressource

Tags: django, vue.js, django-templates, django-csrf, vue-resource

I'm new on Django and Vue.js.
I have an application and I'm trying to post data but I get 403 error (even with CSR token).

Currently, I wrote the following code:

Base template: I get the CSRF token

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
</script>
```

My template where the form is displayed:

```
<form @click.prevent="addtoCart({{article.id}})" method="post" action="{% url 'cart_add' article.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ cart_product_form }}
    <input type="image" src="{% static 'img/icones/shopping-cart.png' %}" alt="shopping-cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
</form
```

My Vue file :

```
methods: {
    addtoCart: function(id) {
        csrftoken = window.csrftoken;
        this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/commander/add/' + id +'/', {headers: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken}});
        console.log(csrftoken);
    }
}
```

My view:

```
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Variations_Articles, id=product_id)
    cart = Cart(request)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        next = cd['next']
        var = cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

My URL:

```
path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add')
```

I can get the CSRF token in the console, but I still get a 403 error.

It has been a couple of days that i'm looking for a mistake but i don't figure out where it is.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Singertwist

Edit 1:

```
addtoCart: function(id) {

    csrftoken = document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').getAttribute("value");
    var data = {                              
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
    'next': window.location.href,
    }
    this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/commander/add/' + id +'/', data);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Solution:
I used the following code for passing my CSRFToken in the header.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  var csrftoken = document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').getAttribute("value");
  request.headers.set('X-CSRFTOKEN', csrftoken)
  next()
})
```

And the view.py:

```
if request.is_ajax():
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        next = data['next']
        comment = data['comment']
        final_composed_cart.add_to_final_composed_cart(categorie_composed_cart=categorie_composed_cart, quantity=1, comment=comment)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

Comment: Did you solve it? Either delete the question or add your solution as a new answer.

Comment: In `this.$http.post`, you are using `csrfmiddlewaretoken` as a header name, so you could probably just change that key into the proper `X-CSRFTOKEN` instead.